# Mysql performance issue: it times out when inserting 10000 records and still take 26 seconds creating 5000 records

Tags: mysql

How can I improve the performance of the below procedure?  What is causing the large delay?

I am using a intel core i5 8th gen chip with 16 Gb of RAM and Mysql 8.0 community edition (default configuration).  The below procedure times out when I set NUMROWS to 10000 and still takes 26 seconds when 5000 is set.

```
        delimiter //

        create procedure rand_data()
        begin
            declare NUMROWS int default 5000;
            declare count int default 0;
        declare fullemail varchar(40) default null;
        declare dateregistered date default null;
        declare activated bool default false;

        drop table if exists users;
        create table users (id int primary key auto_increment, email varchar(40) not null, registered date not null, active bool default false);

        while count < NUMROWS do
            set fullemail := concat('user',count,'name@email.com');
            set dateregistered := date(now() - interval round(10000*rand()) day);
        set activated := round(rand());
        insert into users(email, registered, active) values (fullemail, dateregistered, activated);
        set count := count + 1;
    end while;
end//

delimiter ;
```

Comment: Is the procedure running under a single transaction or 10000 separate transactions?

Comment: I am not sure.  But I did not start a transaction.

Comment: What DB engine are you using? myISAM or InnoDB?

Comment: Since you are creating the table in the procedure, you could try creating it with an `id` field without `primary key` or `auto_increment`, inserting id manually (as count + 1), and then altering the table to make id primary key auto_increment after all inserts are done.

Comment: Using the InnoDB engine.

Comment: removed the primary key and auto_increment then inserted id=count.   still about 24 seconds @Uueerdo

Answer (score 0):

One alternative could be to do a massive insert creating a String and executing when the loop is over

```
CREATE DEFINER=`test`@`%` PROCEDURE `rand_data`()
begin
        declare NUMROWS int default 10000;
        declare count int default 0;
    declare fullemail varchar(40) default null;
    declare dateregistered date default null;
    declare activated bool default false;

    set @query = ' insert into users(email, registered, active) values ';

    drop table if exists users;
    create table users (id int primary key auto_increment, email varchar(40) not null, registered date not null, active bool default false);

    while count < NUMROWS do
        set fullemail := concat('user',count,'name@email.com');
        set dateregistered := date(now() - interval round(10000*rand()) day);
        set activated := round(rand());

        set @query = CONCAT(@query, '(''',fullemail,''', ''',dateregistered,''', ',activated,'),');

        set count := count + 1;
    end while;

    set @query = SUBSTRING(@query, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(@query)-1);
    set @query = CONCAT(@query,';');

    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; 
end
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: I'm not sure if `PREPARE`d statments have a maximum query length, but even if that were the case, they could use this method to break up the inserts into batches of 100 or 1000 at a time; which would probably still help.

Comment: @Jonathan I am not familiar with the prepared statement but it cut the 10000 records down to 2 seconds to finish and I was able to do it without breaking up the inserts.

Comment: The delay you have is for doing 10000 individual insert, you could improve the performance of the insert changing some stuff but you will still doing 10000 individual insert.

But if you do a massive insert, the times slows drastically as you see.

I try not change much you sp so i use the loop to create a dynamic query that create one insert with 10000 records and then execute with [Prepared statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)